# Why lsof reports a higher number of open files of user than what ulimit says should be allowed?

Tags: limit, open-files, lsof, ulimit

I have checked the result for user kpiserv

```
[kpiserv@***** ~]$ lsof -u kpiserv |wc -l  

5358  

[kpiserv@***** ~]$ ulimit -a  

open files                      (-n) 1024
```

Why `lsof` reports a higher number of open files of user than what ulimit says should be allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Open files limit is per process. An user can have multiple processes that total FD count can be greater than open files limit.

From setrlimit(3) man page:

> RLIMIT_NOFILE
>          Specifies a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process. Attempts (open(2), pipe(2),
>   dup(2), etc.)  to exceed this limit yield the error  EMFILE.